# How to open file with python 2.7 in jupyter

Tags: anaconda, jupyter

As title

My Anaconda version is 2.7

I already know how to create a new file in python 2.7 and 3

but when I need to read a file

I don't know how to open my file with python 2.7

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to know what kind of file you're trying to open. Here's the answer from the [Python 2.7 docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).
In essence, 
`f = open('your_file','r')`
where `'r'` is opening the file for reading. Changing it to `'w'` will open the file for writing, and if the files existed it will be overwritten.